# When to release Core Foundation or core graphics object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using core graphics and core foundation object in iOS 10 and iOS 11. When should I release it? Or will it be handled by ARC automatically and I should not bother releasing it?

The reason is because the app crashes if I release a `CGDataProviderRef` 
 using `CGDataProviderRelease(inputPDFDataProvider)`:

```
//file ref
CFURLRef pdfOutputURL = (  CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfOutputPath]);
CFDataRef inputPDFDataRef = (__bridge CFDataRef)inputFileData;
CGDataProviderRef inputPDFDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(inputPDFDataRef);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(inputPDFDataProvider);
numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfRef);

// Release Core Graphics and Core Foundation Object
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef);
//    CGDataProviderRelease(inputPDFDataProvider); **// CRASHES When releasing this CoreGraphics object**
CFRelease(inputPDFDataRef);
CFRelease(pdfOutputURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

As with manual storage management, ownership is the decisive factor. From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH):

> - If you create an object (either directly or by making a copy of another object—see The Create Rule), you own it.
> - If you get an object from somewhere else, you do not own it. If you want to prevent it being disposed of, you must add yourself as an owner (using CFRetain).
> - If you are an owner of an object, you must relinquish ownership when you have finished using it (using CFRelease).

You have to release an object if and only if you're an owner of the object.

But you may transfer the ownership to ARC with [`CFBridgingRelease`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1587932-cfbridgingrelease). If you assign the result of this function to an Objective C variable, you doesn't own the object from the argument anymore.

For your case: You're an owner of `inputPDFDataProvider` because `CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData` matches the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029):

> - Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name;
> - Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name.

Thus, `CGDataProviderRelease` is correct. However, there may be an error in the memory management of `inputFileData`.

Answer (score 0):

'... will it be handled by ARC automatically and I should not bother releasing it?'

Answer is YES, you should always call CFRelease on Core Graphics objects manually to release allocated memory.

About you crash, it shouldn't crush, if you call **CGDataProviderRelease**
Apple Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1408304-cgdataproviderrelease):

*This function is equivalent to CFRelease, except that it does not cause an error if the provider parameter is NULL.*

Comment: That's not always right: You may transfer the ownership to ARC. Transfering can be done even with Core Foundation / Core Graphics objects which have no Objective C equivalent!

Answer (score 0):

Your `inputPDFDataRef` has been assigned through `__bridge` from `inputFileData`. Therefore, there is no transfer of ownership, and you should ***not*** release `inputPDFDataRef` when you are ready with it. It will be released automatically when `inputFileData` is released.

See [this reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id15) for more information.

Comment: Good point, but I would add ownership with CFBridgingRetain instead of a __bridge cast, if it is unclear, when ARC will release inputFileData. If it is a local variable that may occur every time after the last usage of inputFileData.